# Benefits of using Vue.js's Event Bus vs using own implementation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js and I came across the inbuilt Event Bus, I read all of the docs but I am really curious as to what benefits does it give us when we can create our own one and we can use vanilla custom events. So does anyone have any idea what benefit does it give us vs using vanilla JavaScript Event Bus and our own custom events?